# "Uprooting plants IS/ARE/HAD BEEN/WAS like uprooting your life."

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, tense-agreement

Suppose we have to fill in the blank with a correct verb form:

> Uprooting plants ________  like uprooting your life.
>
> Options:
>
> a) is
> b) are
> c) had been
> d) was

I think that the answer ought to be a) since the verb will refer to the act of uprooting but the answer is given as b). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm with you! *Little kids are like little devils.* This way, it takes *are*. I'm trying but not getting an example where the plural *are* is used for a *verb*. There has to be noun in such construction.

Comment: Yes, the main word is *uprooting*, so the answer should be *is* (option A). I'm puzzled at the key giving option B as the correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misread the question? All of these verbs are correct ***except*** b, so maybe the question was: which of these choices is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OP's context, ***uprooting*** is a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) - a verb form functioning as a noun (so in this case, it denotes *the **action** of "to uproot"*).

Although *uprooting* can be used transitively (so it can take an object, such as *plants*, or *your life* here), this doesn't change the fact that *syntactically*, the gerund *uprooting* is a *singular* noun. If we take a slightly different example we see that sometimes it's possible to use a pluralised ***-ing*** form (but I suspect the ***-ings*** forms are probably *not* gerunds, since they can't be used with a direct object)...

> 1: *Beating children is barbaric*
>    2: *Beating the Prince is barbaric*
>    3: *Beating is barbaric*
>    4: *Beatings are barbaric*
>    5: * *Beatings children are barbaric*  (not valid English)

From this it should be clear that regardless of whether a direct object (*children, the Prince*, here) is present, and regardless of whether the object is singular or plural, the ***-ing*** form is always singular unless explicitly pluralised by appending ***-s***.

---

TL;DR: The plural verb form *(**are**)* can never be valid in OP's context. The others are all syntactically valid, but mean different things. In practice, contexts where you might use past *(**was**)* or past perfect *(**had been**)* are contrived and unlikely, so if a single "best" choice must be made, the answer is ***is***.

Answer (score 2):

(B) is definitely wrong.  The subject of the sentence, *Uprooting*, is singular.

(C) is also wrong, due to the improper tense progression.  Past perfect should be used for an action preceding another action in the past, and I don't see any other past tense verb here.

(D) is grammatically possible, but doesn't make much sense.

(A) is correct: this is a simile, in simple present tense, agreeing with a third-person singular subject.

Comment: *"Back in '75 my family was in landscaping, and we took a great deal of personal pride in our designs.  Nothing was more frustrating than when we'd go take a look a year later, and the customer had brought in another crew to change everything.  Uprooting plants was like uprooting your life."*

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the answer should be *is*. That said, I'm with you.

The reason is the verb is referring to a *verb* 'uproot'. I think in construction like this, to have *are*, we must put *noun* at the first place of the sentence.

> Little kids are like little devils

Little kids -*adj+noun* is possible taking the verb *are* but in no case, **a verb at the first place of such sentence can have the verb *is.*** *verb-ing* will be followed by *is*.

Uprooting, the verb is at the first place which is singular and thus, the answer should be *is.*

In that sense, *was* is also grammatically correct but having *is* in the options, this becomes no choice.